# Wait for $http.get to finish when the service is called

Tags: angularjs

I am facing a problem where the controller calls the service function getMyList but myLists is not populated yet as $http call takes some time to complete.

How do I resolve this problem?

Here is my code snippet:

Service

```
app.factory('myService', function($http) {
    var myList = [];

    $http.get("http://myService/json.data").then(function (resp) {
        myLists = resp.data;
    });

    return {
        getMyList: function (name) {
            for (var i = 0; i < myLists.length; i++) {
                if (myList[i].name == name) {
                    return myLists[i];
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Controller:

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function( myService,$scope) {
    var testName = "test"
    myService.getMyList(testName).then(function(resp) {
        // do something with resp data
    });
});
```

Comment: do you have any router? Which of them?

Comment: I don't have a router. But from the controller, I need to call myService.getMyList which returns me a list from the cached myLists

Answer (score 2):

You first need to fix the typos, and choose a better naming. Then you need to return a promise of element rather than an element (that's what the controller expects, by the way):

```
app.factory('myService', function($http) {
    // this defines a promise which, when resolved, contains an array of elements
    var listPromise = $http.get("http://myService/json.data").then(function(resp) {
        return resp.data;
    });

    return {
        // this returns a promise which, when resolved, contains the element with the given name
        getElementFromList: function(name) {
            return listPromise.then(function(list) {
                return list.filter(function(element) {
                    return element.name === name;
                })[0];
            });
        }
    };
});
```

Comment: ok. this is the closest answer to my original question.  I still get resp undefined in my controller class when I call           myService.getElementFromList(testName).then (function(resp)) { // do something}

Comment: Then iyou probably don't have any element in the list with that name. What happens when you debug?

Answer (score 0):

Every HTTP call returns a `promise` in angular, so in your service just return the HTTP call and it return a `promise`.

Then in your controller you can use `then` and `error` call back to handle the response from the `service` or `api` call.

**Factory:**

```
app.factory('myService', function($http) {
    var myList = [];
    return {
        getMyList: function (name) {
            $http.get("http://myService/json.data")
        }
    }
}
```

**Controller:**

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function( myService,$scope) {
    var testName = "test"
    myService.getMyList()
    .then(function successCallback(resp) // Success call back
     {
          if(resp.data)
          {
            myLists = resp.data;
            for (var i = 0; i < myLists.length; i++) {
                if (myList[i].name == testName) { // you can use your testName here itself.
                    return myLists[i];
                }
            }

          }
    },
     function errorCallback(resp)  // Error call back
     {
      console.log(resp)
     });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using some client-side router implementation: have a look at `Route.Resolve` that both [`Ui.Router`](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki#resolve) and [`ngRoute`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/provider/$routeProvider) implement.

If you don't have any router, then, there is a little trick that you can do... Simply return a object reference from your factory, and, when the resolution occurs, fill that object with the expected value:

```js
angular
  .module('test', [])
  .constant('API', 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com')
  .factory("PostResolved", function($http, API) {
    var result = [];
    $http
      .get(API + '/posts/1')
      .then(function(response) {
        result.push(response.data);
      })
    ;
  
    return result;
  })

  .controller('TestCtrl', function($scope, PostResolved) {
    $scope.posts = PostResolved;
  })
;
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<section ng-app="test">
<article ng-controller="TestCtrl">
  <div ng-repeat="post in posts">
    <h1 ng-bind="post.title"></h1>
  </div>
</article>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't use something like below:

```js
app.factory('myService', function($http) {
    return {
        getMyList: function (name) {
            var myList = [];
            $http.get("http://myService/json.data").then(function (resp) {
                myLists = resp.data;
            });
          
            scope.$evalAsync(function () {
                for (var i = 0; i < myLists.length; i++) {
                    if (myList[i].name == name) {
                        return myLists[i];
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The point is I want to call $http.get outside of getMyList method. I need to somehow cache the result of the http call. Not sure about $evalAsync do when I am not storing the result in a scope

Comment: I see, let's try to use $evalAsync to wrap myLists = resp.data; then, hopefully could help

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve this by using $timeout. Anybody who has a better suggestion let me know. I couldn't get scope.$evalAsync to work

Service

```
app.factory('myService', function($http, $timeout) {
    var lists = [];

    $http.get("http://myService/json.data").then(function (resp) {
        lists = resp.data;
    });

    return {
        getMyList: function (name) {
            return $timeout(function() {
                for (var i = 0; i < lists.length; i++) {
                    if (lists[i].name == name) {
                        return lists[i];
                    }
                }
        }, 2000)

    }
}
```

controller

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function( myService,$scope) {
    var testName = "test"
    myService.getMyList(testName).then(function(resp) {
        // do something with resp data
    });
});
```

Comment: This is wrong answer. your http response comes before 2 sec, that's why its working.what if it takes more time.

Comment: yes, I know. I am open to suggestions and improvements

Comment: I have created [pen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/KgQgKk?editors=1011), Similar to your code. I belive JBNizet has given correct answer. Another solution would be $q. But no need of that. As in both cases  your going to return promise.